# Как открыть свернутое приложение на передний план Android

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения, xamarin.android

[Мое приложение](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.my_station) работает по прицепу будильника. И мне нужно в момент подачи сигнала вывести приложение из фона на передний экран(чтобы пользователь нажал на кнопку), не обновляя экран приложения, то есть также, как оно открывается из недавних (фоновых) пользователем.

Как я могу это сделать?